# EnforceUniqueValues attribute on Field definition in Schema.XML not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: list, field-definition

I have the following field definition in the Schema.XML file for a custom list definition. Per the documentation setting EnforceUniqueValues and Indexed to true should enforce a uniqueness constraint on the field, but I am able to add duplicate values across list items through the UI.

```
<Fields>
      <Field Type="Text" 
             DisplayName="Client" 
             Required="TRUE" 
             EnforceUniqueValues="TRUE" 
             Indexed="TRUE" 
             MaxLength="255" 
             ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" 
             SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/Client;}" 
             StaticName="Title" 
             Name="Title" 
             ColName="nvarchar4" 
             RowOrdinal="0" />    
</Fields>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there somewhere else I need to set this attribute?

Comment: Curious.  Was this in the context of a Sandboxed or Farm solution?

Comment: It was a farm solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this for other fields than Title?

The [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.enforceuniquevalues.aspx) for SPField.EnforceUniqueValues states that

> You cannot set this property to true
>   for a built-in field or for a site
>   column.

Not 100% that this is valid for the declarative approachs for custom schemas, but test with another field "test" of type text and you will find out...

**EDIT:**
- Built-in field can be set `EnforceUniqueValues=TRUE`. We have to also set `Indexed=TRUE` & `AllowDuplicateValues=False`. See [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.enforceuniquevalues.aspx#Anchor_2) here and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010134/make-title-field-enforce-unique-values-in-custom-list-definition-sharepoint-201) here.

Comment: Ugh. I bet that's it. SharePoint is a minefield of stuff like this.

Comment: built-in field can be set `EnforceUniqueValues=TRUE` ... We have to also set `Indexed=TRUE` & `AllowDuplicateValues=False` .. Read Remarks Here >> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.enforceuniquevalues.aspx